# Azure Cent OS Unmounts my data Drive

Tags: azure, centos, mount

I have a Cent OS VM instance running on Windows Azure. I have a 1TB data drive mounted to that VM to hold an application's database files. Every week or so at inconsistent intervals, my database crashes and I find that my data drive has been automatically, and without my permission, unmounted.

My data drive still exists with all the data in tact. I have to log in and remount "sudo mount /dev/sdd1 /mount/datadrive". This is frustrating and harmful to my data and the processes that use it.

Also there's nothing in the logs prior to the unmounting and nothing about the drive being unmounted. It's like my drive gets unmounted and the logs get wiped clean. I'm not a linux expert. Do logs get wiped on a reboot? Is my machine getting rebooted and my drives not being re-mounted?

What am I doing wrong? Any idea why this is happening? How can i make it stop? Thanks.

Comment: does the whole VM get rebooted? If so, is that data drive set to auto-mount at boot? You can check for reboots by lookinat the `uptime`. if it's far less than you expect, you've got a fresh boot on your hands.

Comment: Yep. 1 day. Crap. Why is it rebooting my server whenever it feels like it? Is there any way to stop that?

Comment: well, one snarky reason comes to mind: it's microsoft. uptimes in microsoft-land are traditionally measured in minutes/hours... Check the system log (`/var/log/messages`?) and see if there's anything there for around the time the system got rebooted.

Comment: unfortunately it looks like the server doesn't persist logs through a reboot. The logs mention nothing about a reboot and nothing prior to the reboot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Adding_a_New_Disk_Drive_to_a_CentOS_System#Configuring_CentOS_to_Automatically_Mount_a_File_System. You need to configure CentOS to automatically mount the file system.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I will certainly add my drives to the startup file. Luckily my boxes have not been rebooted as of late. Maybe a recent patch has provided more stability to CentOS VMs.

Comment: Thanks and in addition i added my mongod startup line to /etc/rc.loca

Answer (score 0):

There are several way we could understand your problem. What I can suggest is to visit your Management Portal and look for Operation Logs in Settings section to see if there is a log which shows Machine was rebooted. Withing Azure VM reboot logs with time are stored internally so if you open a contact request using Windows Azure Forum [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/WAVirtualMachinesforWindows/threads), we sure can take look about how it is impacting to your problem.

Also when Data disk in not mounted with your Virtual Machine, can you verify if Data Disk shows part of your Virtual Machine in Windows Azure Portal within Virtual Machine Dashboard section?

Data Disk mounts does persist after the VM reboot so I am sure VM reboot could not be your problem. What I suspect is that due to some **unknown issue** the Virtual Machine configuration is leaving the data disk either after the reboot or a Reboot is caused after the problem which return unmounted disk as result. IF you contact Azure VM Support through forum and report problem, I sure can take a look.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I checked the Operation Logs and I see nothing in there about the reboot. I do see the data disk as part of my virtual machine in the azure portal, even when the disk is automatically unmounted. I will go ahead and submit my issue via the Azure forum. Thanks for looking into this for me.

Comment: here's a link to my issue on the Azure VM forum http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/WAVirtualMachinesforWindows/thread/a169a547-3d1b-459e-af65-a1f0089d66d4/#a169a547-3d1b-459e-af65-a1f0089d66d4